# API Response handling in Clean MVVM Architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

I've build app using Clean Architecture now I'm planning to add Network Layer validation into it.

Below is the code how I have implemented this in my app.

```
interface JokeApi {
    @GET("joke/Any")
    suspend fun getJoke(): Response<JokeResponseDto>
}
```

```
class JokeRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val jokeApi: JokeApi) : JokeRepository {
    override suspend fun getJoke(): NetworkResponse<JokeResponse> {
        return handleApiResponse { jokeApi.getJoke() }
    }
}
```

- handleApiResponse function return type is of `NetworkResponse<JokeResponseDto>`

```
suspend fun <T> handleApiResponse(execute: suspend () -> Response<T>): NetworkResponse<T> {
    return try {
        val response = execute()
        val body = response.body()
        if (response.isSuccessful && body != null) {
            NetworkResponse.Success(data = body)
        } else {
            NetworkResponse.Error(errorMessage = response.message())
        }
    } catch (exception: HttpException) {
        NetworkResponse.Error(errorMessage = exception.localizedMessage)
    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        NetworkResponse.Exception(throwable = throwable)
    }
}
```

```
sealed class NetworkResponse<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val errorMessage: String? = null,
    val exception: Throwable? = null,
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : NetworkResponse<T>(data = data)
    class Error<T>(errorMessage: String?) : NetworkResponse<T>(errorMessage = errorMessage)
    class Exception<T>(throwable: Throwable) : NetworkResponse<T>(exception = throwable)
}
```

Issue in this is that retrofit returns the `JokeResponseDto` response object where as `getJoke` function of `JokeRepositoryImpl` expect `JokeResponse` which is valid as case as in this code `mapping` functionality is missing.

I've tried myself to add mapping in handleApiResponse method as it's generic type so not getting much thought on implementation.

Below is the how I'm trying to convert response into another object with necessary details only.

```
class JokeResponseMapper : Mapper<JokeResponseDto, JokeResponse> {
    override fun mapFrom(from: JokeResponseDto): JokeResponse {
        return JokeResponse(
            error = from.error,
            type = from.type.orEmpty(),
            setUp = from.type,
            joke = from.joke,
        )
    }
}
```

```
interface Mapper<F, T> {
    fun mapFrom(from: F): T
}
```

Any help with the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface that maps the response object to the domain model:

```
interface DtoModel<T> {
     fun mapToDomain(): T
}
```

Then change the handleApiResponse like this:

```
 suspend fun <R: DtoModel<T>, T: Any> handleApiResponse(execute: suspend () -> Response<R>): NetworkResponse<T> {
    return try {
        val response = execute()
        val body = response.body()
        if (response.isSuccessful && body != null) {
            NetworkResponse.Success(data = body.mapToDomain())
        } else {
            NetworkResponse.Error(errorMessage = response.message())
        }
    } catch (exception: HttpException) {
        NetworkResponse.Error(errorMessage = exception.localizedMessage)
    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        NetworkResponse.Exception(throwable = throwable)
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
return handleApiResponse { jokeApi.getJoke() }
```

Now the JokeResponseDto has to implements this interface and you have to implement the mapToDomain function inside there.

e.g:

```
class JokeResponseDto(
    ....
    .... 
): DtoModel<JokeResponse> {
     override fun mapToDomain(): JokeResponse {
          return JokeResponse(
              ...
          )
     }
 }
```

Comment: In ```handleApiResponse``` function for this ```Response<DtoModel>)``` getting compile time error stated as ```One type argument expected for interface DtoModel <T>``` its expecting to define type of DtoModel

Comment: Yes you are right, let me check it 5 minutes

Comment: Ok I just updated the functions signature and it seems to be ok, please check it and let me know.

Comment: Pleas also check that now you just call it like this:  `return handleApiResponse { jokeApi.getJoke() }`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple extension function which would map your Dto to Domain model. In your case, it could be:

```
fun JokeDto.toDomain() = JokeDomain(
    text = this.text.orEmpty() // Your joke data
)
```

And when you are returning data to upper layers, your RepositoryImpl could look like this

```
class JokeRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val jokeApi: JokeApi) : JokeRepository {
    override suspend fun getJoke(): NetworkResponse<JokeResponse> {
       return handleApiResponse { jokeApi.getJokeDto().toDomain() }
   }
}
```

Comment: return type of ```handleApiResponse``` function is ```NetworkResponse<T>``` this solution will not work.